# Are $3$ and $19$ the only primes representable by the principal form with discriminant $-57$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-forms, quadratic-reciprocity

I'm trying to see if there are other primes, but so far I only managed to get $3$ and $19$ by factoring $57$. How would I find other primes, if they do indeed exist?

Comment: there is no such form, as $57 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$  and $-57 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Comment: if you switch to discriminant $-228,$  the primes represented by $x^2 + 57 y^2$  are given by congruences, mod 4 and mod 3 and mod 19, as these are one form per disrcriminant. The word for this situation is "idoneal."    Suggest you program numbers $n = x^2 + 57 y^2$ up to, say , 1000, select out just the primes, then ask about the values mod 4,3,19. Oh, there are infinitely such many primes by Cebotarev Density.

Comment: @WillJagy So, since $57 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $-57 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, we are done?

Comment: That really depends on the source of the question; not just the exact wording, also what material is assumed known

Comment: @WillJagy What does $57 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $-57 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ imply in this case, then?

Comment: I see. I'm going to get groceries. Given the other two question about $-39,$ I'm guessing some new computer contest.

Comment: What’s discriminant? It seems sth generated by determinant of a trace matrix?

Answer (score 1):

As Will Jagy says, there is no form of discriminant $-57 = -3 \cdot 10$, so instead we will deal with discriminant $-4\cdot3\cdot19$. Moreover, it is hard to pitch this answer without knowing assumed knowledge, so I'll just write what I'd do. Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-57})$.

We can compute the reducted BQFs of this discriminant as
\begin{align*}
&x^2 + 57y^2 &  3x^2 + 19y^2\\
&6x^2 + 6xy + 11y^2 & 2x^2 + 2xy + 29y^2
\end{align*}
which all correspond to elements of order $2$ in the class group of $K$. Thus the Hilbert Class Field $L/K$ is an everywhere unramified abelian extension of $K$ with Galois group $C_2 \times C_2$. It is easy to check that $L = K(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{19}) = \mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{19})$.

A prime $p \neq 3, 19$ is represented by the principal form if and only if it splits in $L$. This is if and only if $-1$, $3$, and $19$ are squares modulo $p$.

The first is if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so we assume that. For the second
$$\left( \frac{q}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{p}{q} \right)$$
for any odd prime $q$ by our assumption on $p$ and quadratic reciprocity.

Thus $p \neq 3, 19$ is represented if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $p \equiv 1, 4,5,6,7,9,11,16,17 \pmod{19}$.